# Why am I getting syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) on single.php

Tags: php, errors

Here is the code for my Single.php in my theme folder. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
<?php

get_header();

$show_default_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_pb_show_title', true );

$is_page_builder_used = et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( get_the_ID() );

?>

<div id="main-content">
    <?php
        if ( et_builder_is_product_tour_enabled() ):
            // load fullwidth page in Product Tour mode
            while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php
                        the_content();
                    ?>
                    </div> <!-- .entry-content -->

                </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->

        <?php endwhile;
        else:
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php if (et_get_option('divi_integration_single_top') <> '' && et_get_option('divi_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo(et_get_option('divi_integration_single_top')); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' ); ?>>
                    <?php if ( ( 'off' !== $show_default_title && $is_page_builder_used ) || ! $is_page_builder_used ) { ?>
                        <div class="et_post_meta_wrapper">
                            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                        <?php
                            if ( ! post_password_required() ) :

                                et_divi_post_meta();

                                $thumb = '';

                                $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_width', 1080 );

                                $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_height', 675 );
                                $classtext = 'et_featured_image';
                                $titletext = get_the_title();
                                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
                                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                                $post_format = et_pb_post_format();

                                if ( 'video' === $post_format && false !== ( $first_video = et_get_first_video() ) ) {
                                    printf(
                                        '<div class="et_main_video_container">
                                            %1$s
                                        </div>',
                                        $first_video
                                    );
                                } else if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'gallery', 'link', 'quote' ) ) && 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_thumbnails', 'on' ) && '' !== $thumb ) {
                                    print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height );
                                } else if ( 'gallery' === $post_format ) {
                                    et_pb_gallery_images();
                                }
                            ?>

                            <?php
                                $text_color_class = et_divi_get_post_text_color();

                                $inline_style = et_divi_get_post_bg_inline_style();

                                switch ( $post_format ) {
                                    case 'audio' :
                                        $audio_player = et_pb_get_audio_player();

                                        if ( $audio_player ) {
                                            printf(
                                                '<div class="et_audio_content%1$s"%2$s>
                                                    %3$s
                                                </div>',
                                                esc_attr( $text_color_class ),
                                                $inline_style,
                                                $audio_player
                                            );
                                        }

                                        break;
                                    case 'quote' :
                                        printf(
                                            '<div class="et_quote_content%2$s"%3$s>
                                                %1$s
                                            </div> <!-- .et_quote_content -->',
                                            et_get_blockquote_in_content(),
                                            esc_attr( $text_color_class ),
                                            $inline_style
                                        );

                                        break;
                                    case 'link' :
                                        printf(
                                            '<div class="et_link_content%3$s"%4$s>
                                                <a href="%1$s" class="et_link_main_url">%2$s</a>
                                            </div> <!-- .et_link_content -->',
                                            esc_url( et_get_link_url() ),
                                            esc_html( et_get_link_url() ),
                                            esc_attr( $text_color_class ),
                                            $inline_style
                                        );

                                        break;
                                }

                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div> <!-- .et_post_meta_wrapper -->
                <?php  } ?>

                    <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php
                        do_action( 'et_before_content' );

                        the_content();

                        wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'Divi' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );
                    ?>
                    </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
                    <div class="et_post_meta_wrapper">
                    <?php
                    if ( et_get_option('divi_468_enable') == 'on' ){
                        echo '<div class="et-single-post-ad">';
                        if ( et_get_option('divi_468_adsense') <> '' ) echo( et_get_option('divi_468_adsense') );
                        else { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(et_get_option('divi_468_url')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_attr(et_get_option('divi_468_image')); ?>" alt="468" class="foursixeight" /></a>
                <?php   }
                        echo '</div> <!-- .et-single-post-ad -->';
                    }
                ?>

                    <?php if (et_get_option('divi_integration_single_bottom') <> '' && et_get_option('divi_integrate_singlebottom_enable') == 'on') echo(et_get_option('divi_integration_single_bottom')); ?>

                    <?php
                        if ( ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_show_postcomments', 'on' ) ) {
                            comments_template( '', true );
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div> <!-- .et_post_meta_wrapper -->

                     <?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>3
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();?>

<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 100, '...');?></p>
<span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
</div>
</li>
<?
}
echo '</ul><div class="clear"></div></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>


                </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>




            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
    <?php //endif; ?>
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php //get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /var/www/html/jon2/wp-content/themes/macroux/single.php on line 189
The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Comment: You don't have any `while` statement open. Your last `while` on line 168 uses curly braces `{ }` and closes on line 179, so when you get to line 189 the `endwhile` does nothing and confuses PHP. It may help if you work on indenting your code and also always use curly braces, so it's easier to tell where one statement begins and ends. Many editors will show you the paired curly brace when you select one (select the beginning, it will show you the end).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you haven't ended your *second* while loop for `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` being used on line 32

Comment: This was a purchased theme and the person is not responding to correct. I am lost at trying to figure this out.

Comment: Ok - add `<?php endwhile?>` to terminate the loop started at line 32. I've looked at this again - even if you were to resolve this issue you would perhaps encounter a problem for the `endif;` being commented out at the bottom of the file. `get_footer()` also has this problem.

Comment: @JasonBrashear It's not the answer you want, but if a theme has an error like this it's not worth paying for. The code here is embarrassing for a paid product, honestly. You should try your best to get a refund and find another theme that is coded properly.

Comment: @JasonBrashear as Jacob has pointed out this is a poor example of a paid for theme. Out of interest - where did you buy this from?

Comment: Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: @JasonBrashear Have you even attempted to do what I suggested?